# Prediction function in R

Tags: r, prediction, mle

I am working on a data set of employed and unemployed people. After estimation of parameters for (log)wages I am trying to predict values of (log)wages for unemployed people that would correspond with results that I have (in data set values for unemployed are N/A).

After using function predict I still get predictions only for employed people. Does anyone know how to get the full column of "predML"? Thank you in advance!!

```
ml_restricted <- selection(employed ~ schooling + age + agesq + married, logwage ~ schooling + age + agesq, data)
summary(ml_restricted)

# find predicted values

predML <- predict(ml_restricted)

data <- cbind(data, predML)

employed2 <- ifelse(data$employed == 1, "employed", "unemployed")

data <- cbind(data, employed2)
```

Comment: Can you make your post [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? Please provide your data using `dput(data)` and your code within the question itself instead of posting images.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I provided a code but I am not sure if I am allowed to provide entire data online. If it is not possible to solve it without that I understand. Thank you once again!

Comment: where is the `selection()` function from?  The general idea is that you can construct a **minimal** version of your task (e.g. with only a few rows and only one predictor variable?), which still illustrates the problem, so that it's easier to provide the data. Please read the link that @jrcalabrese provided ...

Comment: I guess from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sampleSelection/sampleSelection.pdf ?

Comment: yes, it comes from sampleSelection package

Comment: Does `?predict.selection` help you .... ?? (I don't think I know enough about this fitting methodology to be of much use ...)

Comment: unfortunately I tried that, seems that in any case I am stuck with missing values. Tnx!